# Windows counting connections from localhost for connection limit - how to circumvent?

Tags: windows, networking, file-sharing

This problem actually comes on a build server that is also used as a file server for a small group in a network - unfortunately, we installed a desktop version of Windows with the 20 connection limit.

Strangely now, at the end of the build, output files are copied to a file share - a share that is on the same machine.

I frequently get a message saying

```
Details: No more connections can be made to this remote computer at this time because there are already as many connections as the computer can accept.
```

though.

I did now put the (own) hostname into the hosts file pointing to 127.0.0.1, which so far seems to do the trick of not showing above error.

Still, I am surprised. If I connect to my own computer, even if I say "myhostname", it should be a purely local connection, or does this only work with localhost/127.0.0.1?

Comment: It entirely depends how "myhostname" has been defined.

Comment: It is a Windows Active Directory environment. Still, I suppose the name resolution comes from the DNS server in the network. (I am not that familiar with that..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone (e. g. at work) also runs some jobs on a "server" with a client Windows OS, what I did does the trick, at least for that service.

> I did now put the (own) hostname into the hosts file pointing to 127.0.0.1, which so far seems to do the trick of not showing above error.